# Why does the number of executed AVX instructions change with processor family

Tags: assembly, performancecounter, avx, icc

I have implemented a simple AVX program using intrinsic functions, which is compiled with the icc with `-march=core-avx2 -O3`. The progam does not instrument multithreading.

While profiling the execution of the program I measured the number of actually executed AVX (256-bit Floating point operations) with the PAPI library.

When I execute the programs on different processors (i.e. Core-i7 of Sandy Bridge, Haswell and Skylake) the number of executed instructions is nearly identical for the SB and Skylake architecture but higher (+50%) for the Haswell architecture.

As far as I understand the generated assembler instructions do not differ between the architectures, since `-march=native` is not used.

Where does the difference in executed and *written* operations come from? Is there some sort of micro-code emulation for some hardware/instructions. Or is there some architecture specific overcount happening?

Comment: If you're making any system/library calls it's possible they may contain AVX instructions which may be included in your count ? (E.g. maybe one system uses AVX instructions for memcpy, another uses AVX2, while the third just uses SSE ?)

Comment: There are calls to libraries, but they are outside of the PAPI measurement interval. Also autovectorization of program parts is prohibited.

Comment: What about code that might trigger an implicit memcpy or similar (either inlined or as a library call) ? (Sorry if the questions are dumb - I'm not familiar with PAPI or how you've instrumented your code.)

Comment: PAPI start the measurement a specific point and stops the measurement at another: `start()` and `stop()` between these two I only have plain C and intrinsic code without any other functions.

Comment: OK - I'm out of ideas then - sorry...

Comment: If you're using hardware counters, they tend to be littered with errata. So it might we worth looking at the errata list for Haswell to see if anything looks relevant.

Comment: Yeah, what @Mysticial said. In particular the "FLOPS" type counters have a bunch of caveats (perhaps that's just a euphemism for bugs in many cases). There is a [whole page here](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/FlopsHaswell) which explains the Haswell events and links to another page for the SB and IvB events. It seems clear from those pages that the events are quite different in Haswell versus prior archs. That could explain SB <-> Haswell deviation. Then perhaps the events were fixed up for Skylake, explaining the Haswell <-> Skylake deviation.

Comment: They even talk specifically about `icc` using `ìnsertf128` which gets counted as a computation and potentially inflates counts on Haswell. You could see if Skylake counts that instruction differently with a small test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be divided into at least two questions: 1) are the counters supposed to be the same between two runs? 2) can reported numbers be trusted? The first question addresses possible sources of variation in your methodology, the second one addresses specifics of tools you use (PAPI and underlying hardware counters it uses).

1. Run the same binary on both systems. Not two programs compiled from the same source, but the *same binary file* copied to both of them. If that brings measurements of AVX instructions together, then the problem is that separate compilations generate different code.
2. Simplify the program code so that the resulting number of instructions is trivial to guess. Use a loop with hardcoded number of iterations, with a linear code block inside, and PAPI calls just around the loop. This way, you can predict the outcome, and thus compare it with reported numbers. You use intrinsics, so *one might assume* that compiler optimizations should not affect code generated from them. but reduce the optimization level to `-O0` to make sure the compiler uses minimal amount of tricks, such as dynamic processor dispatching.

   Make the program even simpler. Leave only a single AVX instruction outside any loop. What will PAPI report? Leave zero of them. Will PAPI's report still match the expectation?

These techniques should be enough to logically deduce whether the problem is in discrepancies in build processes of independent binaries, divergence of runtime paths chosen in a single binary on different hardware, incorrect PAPI usage or plain PAPI bugs, possibly caused by underlying hardware being unreliable to count instructions. By the way, you didn't show any code, so it is quite possible that you forgot to initialize something, or have varying number of iterations, or smth similar omission in your approach.

Comment: ICC's code-gen might do dynamic dispatching based on CPUID to tune for different CPUs.  So I'd be worried that `1.` isn't sufficient, depending on what "intrinsics" you used.  Some ICC "intrinsics" like `_mm256_sin_ps` are really SVML library functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes agree, that is why #2 is also needed to maintain one's sanity.  Simplifying one's application so that its properties become statically comprehensive, is a manifestation of universal scientific experimentation approach.

The ultimate answer to "which paths inside a binary are being chosen" would require using a more powerful tool that does dynamic tracing at granularity of instructions. In fact, statistical sampling of RIPs should be enough to find differences in hot code paths. I am not sure if OP has access/knows such tools.

Comment: I mean just doing a `perf stat` and looking at `instructions` (or the equivalent in PAPI) is already a good start. If the instruction counts are quite different you have a strong indication that different paths are being chosen.